# Customize URL landing page for Sign Complete for individual signers in routing

Tags: docusignapi

have a special thing we want to do. Hope you can help, we are using the standard web interface login and powerform templates enabled.

We have 3 different signers for our document
and we want each user to be re-directed to a different URL

User 1 -> URL A;

User 2 -> URL B;

User 3 -> URL C;

Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Right now I know there is a branding section in preferences where we can specificy viewed, complete, finish later, decline, etc. However upon completion of each step we wanted to specify the URL that user is sent to. This would remain the same for all docusigns we send out, this is not unique for each docusign transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible using anything out of the box with DocuSign. The granularity to map different landing pages in DocuSign on a per recipient basis does not exist.

IMO to achieve such a behavior you would need a custom landing page with some business logic that will re-direct the user based off some parameter or information available on the URL. Again, this would be all custom built.